# why zero factorial is equal to one factorial?

Tags: factorial

I will prove 0=1.
we know that, From Factorial definition
zero factorial is equal to one and
one factorial is equal to one.
so,0!=1!.
factorial get cancelled both sides,
we get 0=1.
Is this right..?

Comment: what gives you the right to cancel out the factorial?

Answer (score 3):

What gives you the right to cancel out the factorial? By the same token I can claim that if $x^2 = y^2$ then $x=y$, which implies that since $1^2 = 1 = (-1)^2$, we must have $1 = -1$, just as absurd as your conclusion...

Answer (score 3):

The symbol "!" denotes a function that takes as input nonnegative integers, and has an output defined by a recurrence relation.  Perhaps it might be easier to replace a "!" on the right with something that looks more like traditional functional notation:
$$ \operatorname{fact} : \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0} \to \mathbb{R}
\qquad \text{defined by} \qquad \operatorname{fact}(n) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n=0$, and}\\ n\cdot \operatorname{fact}(n-1) & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
What you are asserting is that
$$
\operatorname{fact}(m) = \operatorname{fact}(n)
\iff m = n.
$$
This is (more or less) the definition of an injective (or one-to-one) function.  If a function is one-to-one, then every *output* corresponds to exactly one input.  When this happens, we can "cancel" the function on two sides of an equation.  However, the factorial function is *not* one-to-one.  As you have already noted,
$$
\operatorname{fact}(0) = \operatorname{fact}(1) = 1.
$$
Since this function is not one-to-one, we can't "cancel" it as you want.

That being said, note that $\operatorname{fact}$ can be restricted to a domain where it *is* one-to-one.  Indeed, it is sufficient to throw away zero.  If you define
$$ \operatorname{fact} : \mathbb{Z}_{> 0} \to \mathbb{R}
\qquad \text{defined by} \qquad \operatorname{fact}(n) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n=1$, and}\\ n\cdot \operatorname{fact}(n-1) & \text{otherwise,}\end{cases}
$$
then you get a one-to-one function that can be "canceled".

Answer (score 1):

Factorial ("!") is not an expression - it is an operator.

For example,
$\sin(0) = \sin(\pi) = 0$
but you can't cancel "sin"
to get
$0 = \pi$.

Comment: for example, x!=5!, we are taking x=5.

Comment: @Rajkumar although there is only one value of $x$ such that $x!=5!$ it is not in general true that there is only one value of $x$ such that $x!=y!$ for arbitrary $y$.  In particular $0!=1!=1$ despite $0\neq 1$.  The fancy phrase to use here is that the factorial is not a one-to-one function.

Comment: What i conclude that ,In order to prove this one , i am redefining the factorial definition as ,n!=n x (n-1) x (n-2) x......x 2 x 1 x 0!.  so according to my definition 1!=1 x 0! .

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. "!" is not a variable rather it is an operator.
2. Factorial function (domain is whole number) is not injective.

Comment: Also, Please do not use the "argument" like this. For example sin(0) = sin(2π). But 2π is not equal to 0